# ListView of CheckBox in Android is visualized by strings instead of Checkboxes

Tags: java, android, listview, checkbox, android-listview

I would like to create `ListView` of checkboxes, pass the `List` to it and when the object is added to list `ListView` will update itself.
I defined `ListView`:

```
 <ListView
        android:id="@+id/productList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >       
    </ListView>
```

I added collection of Checkboxes to the `listView`:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_product_list,
            container, false);
    
    ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.productList);
    ArrayList<CheckBox> list = new ArrayList<CheckBox>();
    CheckBox el = new CheckBox(rootView.getContext());
    el.setText("STH");
    list.add(el);
    ArrayAdapter<CheckBox> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<CheckBox>(rootView.getContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);       
    return rootView;
}
```

**And the result is horrible:**

[image]

I probably get `Checkbox.toString()` inside that `ListView` instead of list of checkboxes.

How to get list of checkboxes which I can tap and select and will be in one container.

Comment: If you downvote say why. I will update the question.

Comment: you add Your checkBox to one list and then generate your adapter, on default `ArrayAdapter` toString() method called and you see that text, best way to do this i think is write your own adapter for populate `CheckBox`

Answer (score 0):

The main problem comes from the fact that you are using 'android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1' for your adapter. This is a built in layout and only contains a single textview.

The best approach is to create you own view that consists of checkbox and textview.

Then create your own adapter to inflate the view and set the contents

```
public class CheckBoxListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

 CheckBox[] boxes;

 public CheckBoxListAdapter(CheckBox[] boxes){
  this.boxes = boxes;
 }
 @Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent{
   View v = inflate.inflate(R.layout.single_list_item, parent, false);

   CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.single_item_cb);
   cb.setChecked(boxes[position].getChecked());

   TextView cb = (TextView )v.findViewById(R.id.single_item_tv);
   cb.setText(boxes[position].getText());

   // Here you can attach listeners and customise components
   return v;
 }
}
```

For the XML view you just need a view with a textview and a checkbox matching those id's

Then just use this as your adapted instead.

Also with this method, as you have a Add button, you can write an add function to the adapter then it can handle your data and display for you :)

Hope this helps

EDIT: Found this, might be useful he explains pretty well http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: you need override more method, like getCount() and getItem() in `baseAdapter`